# Gradle density abi apks

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am generating android apks using gradle with splits.

Following is an example of what I use:

```
splits {
    density {
      enable true
      reset()
      include "mdpi", "hdpi"
    }
    abi {
      enable true
      reset()
      include "x86", "arm64-v8"
    }
}
```

Based on the documentation, it should generate 4 apks mdpi-x86, mdpi-arm64-v8, hdpi-x86 and hpdi-arm64-v8.

However, when I run the gradle script is generated 6 apks, the four above and two more: x86.apk and arm64-v8.apk. I am not sure why those are generated and what is the reason for it. Is there a way not to generate those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you split by density, the Android plugin will always generate an "additional" APK for devices whose screen densities are not supported (at least yet).

As per their [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits?authuser=2#configure-density-split):

> Because each APK that's based on screen density includes a  tag with specific restrictions about which screen types the APK supports, even if you publish several APKs, some new devices will not match your multiple APK filters. As such, Gradle always generates an additional universal APK that contains assets for all screen densities and does not include a  tag. You should publish this universal APK along with your per-density APKs to provide a fallback for devices that do not match the APKs with a  tag.

In your case, because you're also splitting by ABI, you get two "additional" APKs instead of just one.